# getHibernateTemplate.save() - How get Affected rows / New Auto increment

Tags: java, hibernate, save, javabeans

is there a way that i  get back the number of affected rows by using:

```
getHibernateTemplate().save(bean);
```

what is the point using save if you dont know what happened in the end.
Or, if i insert a new row, i want to get the new PK AI that was created....

Any idea?

Thanls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way that i get back the number of affected rows by using:

Not for the "save" operation, which is quite understandable. But if you are using a `Query`, the `executeUpdate` method returns the number of affected records.

> what is the point using save if you dont know what happened in the end.

Well, if there's no exception, you can assume everything went as expected.

> Or, if i insert a new row, i want to get the new PK AI that was created....

Hibernate updates the persisted bean with the generated PK. So, if your bean has a `long id`, set with auto-increment, Hibernate will populate this field once it gets persisted.

Comment: If i understand correctly, I should not use getHibernateTemplate because it is poor in letting you know what went with your requests.